# Sharepoint - where to get started with integrating to another site

Tags: php, sharepoint

We have a sharepoint instance on our network that we get automatically logged into by logging into Windows.  (they do not get prompted to log in)

We have another web application that requires users to log in but it currently has it's own username/password setup.

Our goal is to get the other application (which we have built) to act the same way sharepoint does - if you are logged into windows it will log you right into the application.

Where do I start?  (I assume this will require LDAP)

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Our setup (windows):

```
    Windows
    IE7 & 8
    Windows Active Directory managing users/password
```

Our setup (the other application):

```
    RHEL (could be Windows Server if really necessary)
    PHP 5
    Apache
    mySQL - username and password are stored in mySQL
```

Update: 
Maybe a drawing would help: [Look at this](http://www.gliffy.com/pubdoc/1806214/L.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to implement NTLM Authentication in the PHP application, see my prior answer on this:

[Can a PHP intranet share Windows logins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635171/can-a-php-intranet-share-windows-logins/635230#635230)

Comment: So, I read over the article.  Seems to make sense...What if the servers are 2 separate domains?  One is http://a.com and the other is http://b.com (or even https://b.com)  does it still work then?

Comment: as long as the user opening the page is known in both domains, yes. are they truly separate domains or is one a subdomain?

Comment: One is a windows domain (from AD) the other is not part of an AD domain, it is just a standard URL.  a.com is an AD domain, b.com is nothing more than a domain on the internet.  I've edited my questions to help describe more details.

Answer (score 0):

If your other web application uses Windows Integrated Authentication (NTLM or Kerberos authentication or even basic authentication) then it can act the same way.  Depending on the browser, it can automatically remember and log into sites using one of these methods.  Each browser may do it differently, though.  IE has settings for automatically logging in based on the zone (Internet, Local intranet, trusted sites).

You would not necessarily need to have the have your other application use the same user store (AD/LDAP), but it would likely make sense.