# Fetch Windows Username and Password

Tags: php, windows

I am looking for a way to fetch windows username and password, to log in into LDAP with those credentials.

This code will be on a company's Intranet, so everyone must automatically login. That login must be made with each person's Windows Credentials.

I have searched throught the internet, but didn't find any relevant information, or any that would work properly.

I am using Windows Xp (Don't know if that matters).

thanks

Comment: Check out my answer to this very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635171/can-a-php-intranet-share-windows-logins/635230#635230

Answer (score 0):

Php is server side and its impossible to access any client side info with it. You can use javascript to send data to php but you cant access any windows related credentials with it.